# Assign dictionary value for every item in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, mapping

Making some experiment with Python (3.8) and now I'm stuck with a probably silly problem.

I have a list of objects (actually, dictionaries) and I need to set a value for every entry in the list.

Say my object/dictionary is something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Joe",
    "surname": "Black" 
}
```

for every item in the list, I'd like to assign a new value: `full_name: name + " " + surname`.

At the moment I'm trying something like this (where `records` is my list of dictionaries):

```
records = map(lambda item: item["full_name"] = item["name"] + " " + item["surname"]; return item, records)
```

but probably this is not even valid Python syntax.

Can you suggest me the correct way to achieve this? Is there a way to implement it using for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with a simple for-loop:

```
people = [{
    "name": "Joe",
    "surname": "Black" 
}]

for i in people:
    i["fullname"] =  i["name"] + " " + i["surname"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve this, Please note that this create entirely new list with dictionary objects.

```
>>> records = [{"name": "Joe1", "surname": "Black"}, {"name": "Joe2", "surname": "Black"}]
>>>
>>> result = [
...     {**record, "fullname": record["name"] + " " + record["surname"]}
...     for record in records
... ]
>>> print(result)
[{'name': 'Joe1', 'surname': 'Black', 'fullname': 'Joe1 Black'}, {'name': 'Joe2', 'surname': 'Black', 'fullname': 'Joe2 Black'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding another version:

```py
lst = [{"name": "Joe", "surname": "Black"}]

lst = [dict(full_name=f'{d["name"]} {d["surname"]}', **d) for d in lst]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
[{'full_name': 'Joe Black', 'name': 'Joe', 'surname': 'Black'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution will work, but actual creates a copy of the list `records` with modification in the variable `result`; if you want to simply add the attribute to the existing items in the existing list you can do the following:

```
for record in records:
    record["fullname"] = f"{record['name']} {record['surname']}"
```